# Moving just the DokuWiki data directory on other server

Tags: php, iis7, iis, dokuwiki

I have installed DokuWiki on IIS7. As per my teams requirement we have to move just the Data directory to other server location, e.g.:

- IIS7 installed DokuWiki location: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dokuwiki\conf`
- data location on the other server we want: `U:\Archive\LP_Archive\SH_Systems\DEV01\dokuwiki`

So for doing that I followed pointers on [DokuWiki install IIS7](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:iis?s%5B%5D=iusr#iis7). As per the above link, I tried adding IUSR to data folder permissions but it’s failing due to my insufficient privileges. And without that IUSR permission set on data folder I am getting an error as:

> The datadir ('pages') at is not found, isn't accessible or writable.

Is there any other way to make it work? Is there any other account than IUSR I can use?

Comment: I think you would get better information regarding this on serverfault SE

Comment: did you change the local.php to address the new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me with these settings

1. Moved the complete DokuWiki installation on other machine Now IIS
   on HPV-SHSDEV1-01 points to DokuWiki installation at this location
   \co-lp-vmpfile2\SH_custom_applications\SH_Systems\DEV01\dokuwiki\dokuwiki
2. Changed anonymous user's indentity to App pools identity
3. Used UNC path instead of mapped drive path to locate folder from IIS